# Clean way of passing parameters in swift

Tags: design-patterns, swift, ios, web-services, file-structure

I am creating a user request model to pass-params for web service call

- toRegisterParams() is used call register web service request
- toLoginParams() is used call register web service request
- so my question is this correct way or I need to Optimise my code
  or I should make different models for the same. As most-of parameters are the same.
- for example, if I need add param in login service there are more probability to add the same in register service param.

  ```
   struct UserResquest
  {
      var phone: String = ""
      var countryPhoneCode: String = ""
      var referralCode: String = ""
      var firstName : String = ""
      var lastName : String = ""
      var email: String = ""
      var country: String = ""
      var loginBy: String = CONSTANT.MANUAL
      var socialUniqueID: String = ""
      var password: String = ""

      /**
       * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
       */
      func toRegisterParams() -> [String:Any] {
          var dictParam: [String:Any] = [:]
          dictParam[PARAMS.PHONE] = phone
          dictParam[PARAMS.COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE] = countryPhoneCode
          dictParam[PARAMS.APP_VERSION] = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String)
          dictParam[PARAMS.EMAIL] = email
          dictParam[PARAMS.LAST_NAME] = firstName
          dictParam[PARAMS.FIRST_NAME] = lastName
          dictParam[PARAMS.DEVICE_TOKEN] = preferenceHelper.getDeviceToken()
          dictParam[PARAMS.DEVICE_TYPE] = CONSTANT.IOS
          dictParam[PARAMS.DEVICE_TIMEZONE] = TimeZone.current.identifier
          dictParam[PARAMS.COUNTRY] = country
          dictParam[PARAMS.LOGIN_BY] = loginBy
          if loginBy != CONSTANT.MANUAL {
              dictParam[PARAMS.SOCIAL_UNIQUE_ID] = socialUniqueID
              dictParam[PARAMS.PASSWORD] = ""
          } else {
              dictParam[PARAMS.SOCIAL_UNIQUE_ID] = ""
              dictParam[PARAMS.PASSWORD] = password
          }
          return dictParam
      }

      func toLoginParams() {
          var dictParam: [String:Any] = [:]
          dictParam[PARAMS.APP_VERSION] = (Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String)
          dictParam[PARAMS.EMAIL] = phone
          dictParam[PARAMS.COUNTRY_PHONE_CODE] = countryPhoneCode
          dictParam[PARAMS.DEVICE_TIMEZONE] = TimeZone.current.identifier
          dictParam[PARAMS.DEVICE_TYPE] = CONSTANT.IOS
          dictParam[PARAMS.SOCIAL_UNIQUE_ID] = ""
          dictParam[PARAMS.DEVICE_TOKEN] = preferenceHelper.getDeviceToken()
          dictParam[PARAMS.LOGIN_BY] = CONSTANT.MANUAL
          dictParam[PARAMS.PASSWORD] = password
          dictParam[PARAMS.PHONE] = phone
          return dictParam
      }
  }
  ```

let me explain the scenario

in my app user can login throught phone number 
 - in first screen user inputs the mobile number and place submit button (which call api and check number exist or not)

- if yes then password screen will display when user enter password login api call with above params
- If number is not registered register screen will display with entered mobile number and then user can't edit number as it verified by otp. after fill form register api call with above param.

Comment: Both `toRegisterParams()` and `toLoginParams()` are described as “used call register web service request” – copy/paste error?

Comment: Is `dictParam[PARAMS.EMAIL] = phone` a typo?

Comment: yes,  its a typo

Comment: toRegisterParams() used to pass register params while  toLoginParams() to pass login params there is no error everything work perfect, but i want to know is it correct way or not.

Comment: Did you fill it once one-time and then call the services? When they are on different places filled then I would do 2 different structs

Comment: @muescha I have updated the question with description.

Comment: then i miss a `toCheckPhoneParams` here.... if you like to reuse all in one step

Comment: i would extract all device infos which are the same in both calls into ohne method where you init the `dictParam` -> `var dictParam: [String:Any] = getDeviceInfo()`